# How is ruby on rails has_many (and similar) implemented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, implementation, has-many

I am analysing the rails source code, because I wold like to understand the inner workings of the `has_many` and similar constructs.

So far, I was able to find where the method is implemented ([link to github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/109db5a55035781166f295d38a2702ce3cc83858/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb)): it is in the module ActiveRecord::Associations

```
def has_many(name, options = {}, &extension)
  Builder::HasMany.build(self, name, options, &extension)
end
```

This one eventualy ends ([link to github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/109db5a55035781166f295d38a2702ce3cc83858/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb)) in the class ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::CollectionAssociation as

```
def self.build(model, name, options, &extension)
  new(model, name, options, &extension).build
end
```

There is where my ruby skills end and I could not track it further and find where is "new" implemented and what it does.

Can someone point me to the right direction and maybe comment along, what is going on under the hood?

Comment: +1 for perusing the source code of the tools you're using in order to gain a deeper understanding of their internals. Way to go.

Comment: @s.m.: I agree. If reading the source code doesn't "show research effort" (as the tooltip for the upvote button says), I don't know what does! +1!

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering. I accepted Jörg's answer, because it is most detailed. I also +1 Baldrik and s.m. for being the first who answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, `new` is defined like this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate

    obj.initialize(*args, &block)
    # *actually* obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block) since initialize is private

    obj
  end
end
```

`allocate` is defined like this:

```
class Class
  def allocate
    # magic stuff for creating an empty object which cannot be expressed in Ruby:

    new_obj = Deep::Within::VM.__somehow_magically_allocate_memory__!

    new_obj.__class__ = self

    new_obj
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`new` calls the constructor of the current class. The constructor is the method `initialize` that is defined just after `self.build` method in the class `CollectionAssociation` . It's pure Ruby ([ruby guide](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html))

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Baldrick's answer, which is correct, `new` is defined in `Class` as both a class method and an instance method, and is hence available to all classes.

What `new` does is invoking both [`allocate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-allocate) and `initialize` (assuming an `initialize` method has been defined).

Comment: I don't think `new` is defined as a class method. The `Class` class is an instance of itself (yay, circularity!), that's why `Class.new` works.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm not an expert of Ruby's internals whatsoever, but the documentation shows that new is both a class and instance method of Class, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Actually, that's the documentation for `Class#initialize`. RDoc just *shows* it as the documentation for `Class::new`. It does this for *all* classes, because that's how you normally *use* the `initialize` method. You don't actually call it, you have `new` call it for you. If you look at the source code, you can see that the documentation block sits atop the `rb_class_initialize` function which corresponds to the `Class#initialize` method.